# Ошибка 401 при запросе GET, Python

Tags: python, get, request

На сайте указано [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код примерно (пишу на работе, по памяти):

```py
t = requests.get('https://mrecord.mts.ru/api/v3/recs/9160551823/2019-07-24T00:00:00/2019-07-28T23:59:59', auth = ('Basic', 'bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ='))
print(t)
```

выдает 401 код. Это мои первые начинания, не понимаю что не так. Подскажите в чем может быть причина

Comment: Может потому, что вы неверные идентификационные данные в Basic указываете?

Comment: А разве Basic и bG9na... не данные для входа, логин/пароль, указанные в роли примера?

Comment: Вот именно, в качестве примера. Если вы в реальный запрос подставляете данные из примера, ничего хорошего не выйдет

Comment: Этот пример я указал как пример (тавтология/), использую я свои данные для входа, они чучуть приватные